# How to execute SQL files with Azure DevOps or Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I have Folder "SQLFiles" in Azure DevOps Repo. I have there sql files like Insert_Customers.sql, which make Insert Into statements. There are 50 SQL files.

How to create daily automatic solution which execute SQL scripts to create tables if there are new files created?

Should I insert rows with Azure DevOps or should I insert rows with Azure Data Factory?

Should I first upload files to Azure Storage in case of executing files from  Data Factory?

Comment: Terraform would have no triggers for new files pushed to a Azure DevOps repository & is related to infrastructure so removing TF flag - feel free to readd in + supporting info if I've misunderstood the Q.

Comment: What is the purpose of these insert files? Is it for static data? Do these files need to be executed each time the file gets updated?

Comment: I'm thinking now that that I load files to Azure Storage with Terraform and then read files with ADF so that I can execute SQL statements related to system testing defined in files.